# Calling an oracle stored proc that returns a strong record type

Tags: oracle, vb6

I have a stored proc in oracle that looks like this:

```
PROCEDURE get_protection_details (  
             i_case_key     IN  NUMBER, 
             i_eff_dt       IN  DATE,
             protection_rec OUT protection_rectype
          )
```

The output parameter is type record - declared in the package like this:

```
TYPE crms_protection_rectype IS RECORD (
     active_protection_flag VARCHAR2(1)  := NULL,
     protection_type        VARCHAR2(30) := NULL,
     term                   VARCHAR2(30) := NULL,
     protection_fee_name    VARCHAR2(30) := 'PROTECTION'
);
```

I am trying to call this from VB6 - here is the code I have

```
Dim adoCMD As Object
Dim rs as ADODB.recordset

Set adoCMD = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
adoCMD.ActiveConnection = Me.Cn
adoCMD.CommandText = "fdp$product.get_protection_details"
adoCMD.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
adoCMD.Parameters.Append adoCMD.CreateParameter("i_case_key", adDouble, adParamInput, 32000, plCaseKey) 
'//this case key is type long and value is 20305003'
adoCMD.Parameters.Append adoCMD.CreateParameter("i_eff_dt", adDate, adParamInput, 32000, Format(Now(), "DD/MM/YYYY"))
rs = adoCMD.Execute
```

I get an error saying incorrect number of parameters - tearing my hair out over something that should be pretty easy - how do you call a stored proc that returns a defined record type?

Have examples everywhere that returns a weak cursor in this way.

Is there a way to define the record in vb6 somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you haven't defined the output parameter.

```
adoCMD.Parameters.Append adoCMD.CreateParameter("protection_rec", adXXXX, adParamOutput, nnnnn)
```

The only thing is, I don't know if you can do this, and with what type. Maybe adLongVarBinary would work, and you would have to copy chunks of data out of the resulting buffer.

Why can't you simply return the data as a standard recordset, i.e. change your stored procedure to do the following:

```
SELECT active_protection_flag, protection_type, term, protection_fee_name
```

If there is a good reason not to change your stored procedure's interface, maybe you could create a wrapper stored procedure which essentially converts the output parameters into a SELECT statement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you're right on the problem. I couldn't use any of the standard adxxxx to define the return. I guess there isn't a way of doing this directly. I didn't write the oracle part, I'll have to get that person to update the stored proc appropriately. Thanks for the help